# SQL Server convert sum of column with multiple conditions into new column of same conditioned data

Tags: sql-server, sum, formula, multiple-conditions

I have a table of golf data. Each golfer has a final score (round_score column) for each round of a given tournament. I want to add all of the round scores up for each golfer and store it in the final_score column. I want this final_score number to stay the same for all rows for that golfer for a tournament. But it's producing different numbers for each row.

The finalscore_points column is a formula: final_score * -3. So of course I do not want that number to change, too, for all rows of for a golfer in a given tournament.

For example: If golfer A's summed round_score from rounds 1-4 = -2, then I want the final_score column in each row (split by round, tournament_id, and year) to have -2 as its value.

How would I go about doing this?

```
    Select player_id, full_name, [year] ,tournament_id, [round], 
    round_score, sum(round_score) as final_score, sum(round_score) * -3 as 
    finalscore_points 
    From v_temptable6
    Group By player_id, full_name, [year] ,tournament_id, [round], 
    round_score
    Order by [year], tournament_id, full_name, [round], round_score
```

Edit:

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNZ0f.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like following query. Here the `RoundScore` is the `SUM` of all the round for each `Tournament` for the player.

```
SELECT   *,(RoundScore * -3) AS FinalScore 
FROM     ( 
            SELECT   player_id, 
                    full_name, 
                    [year] , 
                    tournament_id, 
                    [round], 
                    round_score, 
                    Sum(round_score) OVER(PARTITION BY player_id,tournament_id ORDER BY player_id) AS RoundScore 
            FROM     v_temptable6 
          ) T 
ORDER BY [year], 
         tournament_id, 
         full_name, 
         [round]
```

Sample Example

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(Player_Id VARCHAR(100), Full_Name VARCHAR(100), [Year] INT, tournament_id INT, Round int, Round_Score INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE
SELECT 'C3CCE201-9176-4910-9916-253FCFBE7899','AB',2013,1,1,3
INSERT INTO @TABLE
SELECT 'C3CCE201-9176-4910-9916-253FCFBE7899','AB',2013,1,2,3    

INSERT INTO @TABLE
SELECT '51FB1D63-C925-4E69-B89B-2566271A8C8C','AC',2013,1,1,7

INSERT INTO @TABLE
SELECT '51FB1D63-C925-4E69-B89B-2566271A8C8C','AC',2013,1,2,5

INSERT INTO @TABLE
SELECT 'EE6036AF-3C74-4F34-94CE-7695473ADB04','BC',2013,1,1,-2

INSERT INTO @TABLE
SELECT 'EE6036AF-3C74-4F34-94CE-7695473ADB04','BC',2013,1,2,2

INSERT INTO @TABLE
SELECT 'EE6036AF-3C74-4F34-94CE-7695473ADB04','BC',2013,1,3,-1

INSERT INTO @TABLE
SELECT 'EE6036AF-3C74-4F34-94CE-7695473ADB04','BC',2013,1,4,7



SELECT   *,(RoundScore * -3) AS FinalScore 
FROM     ( 
            SELECT   player_id, 
                    full_name, 
                    [year] , 
                    tournament_id, 
                    [round], 
                    round_score, 
                    Sum(round_score) OVER(PARTITION BY player_id,tournament_id ORDER BY player_id) AS RoundScore 
            FROM     @TABLE 
          ) T 
ORDER BY [year], 
         tournament_id, 
         full_name
```

Output:

```
+--------------------------------------+-----------+------+---------------+-------+-------------+------------+------------+
| player_id                            | full_name | year | tournament_id | round | round_score | RoundScore | FinalScore |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+------+---------------+-------+-------------+------------+------------+
| C3CCE201-9176-4910-9916-253FCFBE7899 | AB        | 2013 | 1             | 1     | 3           | 6          | -18        |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+------+---------------+-------+-------------+------------+------------+
| C3CCE201-9176-4910-9916-253FCFBE7899 | AB        | 2013 | 1             | 2     | 3           | 6          | -18        |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+------+---------------+-------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 51FB1D63-C925-4E69-B89B-2566271A8C8C | AC        | 2013 | 1             | 1     | 7           | 12         | -36        |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+------+---------------+-------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 51FB1D63-C925-4E69-B89B-2566271A8C8C | AC        | 2013 | 1             | 2     | 5           | 12         | -36        |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+------+---------------+-------+-------------+------------+------------+
| EE6036AF-3C74-4F34-94CE-7695473ADB04 | BC        | 2013 | 1             | 1     | -2          | 6          | -18        |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+------+---------------+-------+-------------+------------+------------+
| EE6036AF-3C74-4F34-94CE-7695473ADB04 | BC        | 2013 | 1             | 2     | 2           | 6          | -18        |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+------+---------------+-------+-------------+------------+------------+
| EE6036AF-3C74-4F34-94CE-7695473ADB04 | BC        | 2013 | 1             | 3     | -1          | 6          | -18        |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+------+---------------+-------+-------------+------------+------------+
| EE6036AF-3C74-4F34-94CE-7695473ADB04 | BC        | 2013 | 1             | 4     | 7           | 6          | -18        |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+------+---------------+-------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. The newly created RoundScore column does not add up to the correct sum.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data to check

Comment: I tried posting a picture of my data, but the link to the pic is not showing up in my edit above.

Comment: I have updated the anser, can you check as I don't find any issue in the output.

Comment: Your new code didn't work. Although I figured it out. I added: PARTITION BY player_id, tournament, [year]....  and it worked! Thanks for your help!

Comment: I assumed tha tournament Id will be unique for every year so excluded it from the partition, if your query is resolved you can mark it as accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

why you are grouping round_score also Remove Round Score from group by clause
and add `MIN(round_score)` in select

`Select player_id, full_name, [year] ,tournament_id, [round], 
MIN(round_score), sum(round_score) as final_score, sum(round_score) * -3 
finalscore_points 
From v_temptable6
Group By player_id, full_name, [year] ,tournament_id, [round]
Order by [year], tournament_id, full_name, [round], round_score`

Comment: Because round_score is a non-formula column. It's a regular column just like player_id, full_name, [year] ,tournament_id, and [round].

Comment: Ok I got your problem try Joining that table with Inner query on same table which output columns like player_id,tournament_id,sum(round_score) as final_score, sum(round_score) * -3 as finalscore_points and join this Inner query to main table with player_id,tournament_id it will give the result as you are expecting

Comment: try this 
`SELECT T1.player_id, T1.full_name, T1.[year] , T1.tournament_id, T1.[round], 
    T1.round_score,T2.final_score,T2.finalscore_points
From v_temptable6 T1
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT player_id,
       tournament_id,
    sum(round_score) as final_score,
      sum(round_score) * -3 as finalscore_points 
FROM v_temptable6
Group By player_id, tournament_id) T2 ON T1.player_id = T2.player_id AND T1.tournament_id = T2.tournament_id
Order by [year], tournament_id, full_name, [round], round_score`